# Proving positivity of high degree homogenous polynomials in 4 variables

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have several homogenous polynomials of degrees 6, 8,.... They are in 4 different variables A,B,C,D.

I need to show that they are positive for any positive value of A,B,C,D.

Looking at a plot of the curves I find that they do seem to be positive for all values of A,B,C,D.

I have tried to find the minimum by solving the system of odd-degree homogenous partial differential equations for zero but the computer seems unable to solve these after leaving for 24 hours or so.

I'm wondering if there is any theory on proving homogenous polynomials are positive. Or to look for the roots and prove that either there are none, or that the roots are double etc.

The polynomials are very long, here is one of the degree 6 ones:

\begin{equation*}
%\resizebox{1.4\textwidth}{!}{$
\begin{gathered}
\begin{aligned}
{A}^{6}\\
+ \bigg( {\frac {197\,B}{290}}+{\frac {241\,C}{
435}}+{\frac {241\,D}{435}} \bigg) {A}^{5}\\
+ \bigg( {\frac {
3641\,{C}^{2}}{16704}}+ ( {\frac {1027\,D}{41760}
}+{\frac {61\,B}{174}} ) C+{\frac {77\,{B}^{2}}{464}}+{\frac {3641\,{D}^{2}}{16704}}+{\frac {61\,
B\,D}{174}} \bigg) {A}^{4}\\
+ \bigg( {\frac {997\,{
C}^{3}}{20880}}+ ( -{\frac {101\,D}{20880}}+{
\frac {2479\,B}{20880}} ) {C}^{2}\\
+ ( -{
\frac {101\,{D}^{2}}{20880}}+{\frac {529\,{B}^{2}}{
6960}}+{\frac {65\,B\,D}{2088}} ) C+{
\frac {529\,{B}^{2}D}{6960}}+{\frac {2479\,B\,
{D}^{2}}{20880}}+{\frac {21\,{B}^{3}}{1160}}+{\frac {
997\,{D}^{3}}{20880}} \bigg) {A}^{3}\\
+ \bigg( {\frac {547\,{
C}^{4}}{83520}}+ ( -{\frac {13\,D}{2610}}+
\frac{B}{48} ) {C}^{3}+ ( {\frac {25\,{D}^{
2}}{8352}}+{\frac {449\,{B}^{2}}{20880}}+{\frac {B\,
D}{464}} ) {C}^{2}\\
+ ( -{\frac {13\,{
D}^{3}}{2610}}+{\frac {{B}^{3}}{145}}+{\frac {3\,{
B}^{2}D}{464}}+{\frac {B\,{D}^{2}}{464
}} ) C+{\frac {{B}^{4}}{1160}}+{\frac {{B}^{3}D}{145}}+{\frac {449\,{B}^{2}{D}^{2}}{
20880}}+\frac{1}{48}\,B\,{D}^{3}+{\frac {547\,{D}^{4}
}{83520}} \bigg) {A}^{2}\\
+ \bigg( {\frac {{C}^{5}}{1740}}+
 ( -{\frac {D}{1044}}+{\frac {79\,B}{41760}}
 ) {C}^{4}+ ( {\frac {{D}^{2}}{2610}}+{
\frac {11\,{B}^{2}}{4176}}-{\frac {B\,D}{5220}
} ) {C}^{3}\\
+{\frac { ( 2\,B+2\,D
 ) {C}^{2}}{1305} ( {B}^{2}-{\frac {15\,
B\,D}{32}}+\frac{1}{4}\,{D}^{2} ) }+ ( -{
\frac {{D}^{4}}{1044}}+{\frac {{B}^{3}D}{10440
}}+{\frac {17\,{B}^{2}{D}^{2}}{20880}}-{\frac {
B\,{D}^{3}}{5220}}+{\frac {{B}^{4}}{3480}}
 ) C\\
 +{\frac {D}{3480} ( {B}^{4}+\frac{16}{3}\,{B}^{3}D+{\frac {55\,{B}^{2}{D}^{2}
}{6}}+{\frac {79\,B\,{D}^{3}}{12}}+2\,{D}^{4}
 ) } \bigg) A\\
+{\frac {{C}^{6}}{41760}}+ ( {\frac {
B}{13920}}-{\frac {D}{20880}} ) {C}^{5}+
 ( -{\frac {{D}^{2}}{41760}}+{\frac {{B}^{2}}{
8352}}-{\frac {B\,D}{41760}} ) {C}^{4}\\
+ ( {\frac {{B}^{3}}{10440}}+{\frac {{D}^{3}}{
10440}}+{\frac {{B}^{2}D}{20880}}-{\frac {B\,{
D}^{2}}{20880}} ) {C}^{3}+ ( {\frac {{
B}^{4}}{20880}}-{\frac {{D}^{4}}{41760}}+{\frac {{
B}^{2}{D}^{2}}{20880}}-{\frac {B\,{D}^
{3}}{20880}} ) {C}^{2}\\
+{\frac {{D}^{3} ( {
B}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\,B\,D-{D}^{2} ) 
C}{20880}}+{\frac { ( {B}^{2}+B\,D+{D}^{2} ) {D}^{2} ( {B}^{2}+
B\,D+\frac{1}{2}\,{D}^{2} ) }{20880}}
 \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
 %$}
\end{equation*}

Comment: How long is "very long"? If the fit in a few lines, it may be helpful to give one of them...

Comment: "I'm wondering if there is any theory..." Yes, there is. You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial

Comment: So you may try to multiple it by a certain power of $A+B+C+D$ and check whether all coefficients are positive:)

Comment: This refinement of Fedor's suggestion might help. The Newton polytope of $f$ is the convex hull of the set $w = (a,b,c,d)$ where $A^aB^bC^cD^d$ appears in $f$. Restrict $f$ to the faces, giving lower dimensional polynomials. Check if these polynomials are positive on the positive orthant. If so, let $Q$ be the polynomial which has coefficient 1 at every lattice point where the coefficient of the original is nonzero. It is a theorem that there exists $n$ such that $Q^n f$ has no negative coefficients iff $f$ is strictly positive on the positive orthant [when the facial conditions hold].

Comment: But isn't checking whether a polynomial is strictly positive on the positive orthant NP-complete?

Comment: Or $Q$ can be less complicated: any $Q$ which has a positive coefficient at every lattice point in the Newton polytope will do (the only difference will be the $n$).